Calling function on solidity contract fom JS
I have a sample contract running on a remix IDE that im trying to call a function from my js but it doesnt seem to be working. I can print the functions on the contract. But i cannot get the getGreeting() function to work and print the string inside the solidity contract. Its supposed to just return a string that says "this is a string from solidity". It says the ABI is not right or the gas fees i get the error message
 { cause: undefined, code: 205, props: { internalErr: AbiError: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contr act you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced. }
// packages
const Web3 = require('web3');
require('dotenv').config();

const infuraProjectId = 'my-id';
const endpoint = `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${infuraProjectId}`;
console.log(Object.keys(Web3));
const httpProvider = new Web3.HttpProvider(endpoint);
const contractABI = ["my-ABi"];// is copied from remix


const contractAddress = '0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138';
const contract = new Web3.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);
contract.setProvider(httpProvider.clientUrl);


console.log('Contract initialized');
console.log('Contract methods:', contract._methods)


contract._methods.getGreeting().call()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);  // Print the result of getGreeting()
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);  // Handle any errors that occurred during the call
}); ```


Your Infura is pointing to mainnet. Are you sure you are testing on mainnet? If yes, you really shouldn't

The issue looks in this line

const endpoint = https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${infuraProjectId};

The infura URL you have selected is of ethereum mainnet.
If you are testing on any testnets like ethereum sepolia testnet or Polygon Amoy, you should use that particular url.
You will need to activate that endpoint from your Infura app. Just tick mark the network which you want to use.
For eg. for ethereum sepolia testnet it will be:
https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/${infuraProjectId}

okay let me try. I ran the code on remix cancun. I will try to use sepolia and change it and see what happens

well looks like i need to add funds if i switch the network. I think i want to keep mantenent because the contract will be ERC721.

doesn't seem to be the issue. I have the sepolia endpoint active it says i have 75 requests today in the mainnet tab. So it should be something with the ABI. Its making the request but not calling the function. The function is pure so it should be callable. I did not put external though only pure.

You need to put external the function to be able to call it. The pure keyword is used to show that the function doesn't view or update the state of the blockchain.
Every function needs to have the visibility modifier like 'public', 'external', 'private' and 'internal'.

okay i modified the function but it didn't work. I get the same error. The function looks like this function getGreeting() external pure returns (string memory) {
// pure indicates that function does read or access the blockchain state
return "Hello world this is a solidity string";
} and my contract address is running i will keep it up. It is deployed at 0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138. I can print the functions. But im not using web3.eth.contract instead just web3.contract. Don't know if this makes a difference. Still getting the same error

it is running on remix VM sepolia fork. I tried to do on the sepolia test net but i need real money i guess.

another weird thing is that if i try to find the contract on etherscan it doesn't say test it says a real contract lol
